# "failing sun" meaning

Tags: word-meaning, phrase-meaning

What does the failing sun mean? Is it the same as the setting sun?

As in:

> He struggled up, shivering, vaguely surprised that he was still wet to his skin, and saw the cup lying innocently in the grass before him and the lake, deep-blue shot with gold in the **failing sun**.
>
> <sub>Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows</sub>

Comment: Yes. It means the setting sun.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, "failing sun" here means the sun was setting then.

From Cambridge, "[failing](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/failing)" (adjective) means

> becoming weaker or less successful
>
> - failing eyesight
> - **In the failing light**, it was hard to read the street signs.

Macmillan Dictionary says *"no longer strong or healthy"* (adjective). Note that I can't find the adjective form of the word in Collins or Merriam-Webster.

Comment: But only in *this* context. In the context of a science fiction story in which the sun is about to explode, it would *not* mean that the sun was simply setting. In fact, if I hadn't read *Harry Potter and the Deathly Hollows*, but did know it was a fantasy book, I still might not assume it was simply setting.